# treeEquals function - error in my private call

Tags: java

Im having trouble calling the correct parameters in my private method. 
`MyIntSET` is a `Node` so I can't call `MyIntSET` but instead the `root`... I still get an error in Eclipse stating: `"This method must return a result of type boolean"`

Any suggestions?

```
/* Returns true if this tree and that tree "look the same." (i.e. They have
     * the same keys in the same locations in the tree.)
     * Note that just having the same keys is NOT enough.  They must also be in
     * the same positions in the tree.
     */
```

the link to the image is down below:
[image]

***update: I added a return false statement outside of the if in my public statement****
I ran a JUnit Test, but still fails...

anything I'm missing?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please post your code as text, not as image. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask how you can improve your question further.

Answer (score 0):

the error you getting is cause you need to specify what `treeEquals` return if the if condition is **not** met, if roots aren't `null` you need to go on and compare both tries

try this

```
public boolean treeEquals(MyIntSET that) {
  if (root == null && that.getRoot() == null)
    return true;

  return treeEquals(root, that.getRoot());
}
```

assuming you have a getter for the root node of `MyIntSET` class

Comment: that is a great help! Thank you! however, unfortunately, I cannot add a getRoot()  method to the class. I'm limited for this homework

Comment: Instead i removed .get and modified to: `that.root`, works the same as I had, however, same error in my Junit. Thank you so much!